# Performance of Rails transaction rollback vs. manual cleanup in Production DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, transactions, rollback

**I am aware that a rollback is not the same thing as a manual cleanup and is, in most cases,  the preferred approach. That said, what is the performance difference between a large database rollback versus a manual cleanup if there are concurrent saves and deletes in other tables in the database?**

---

Additional details:

I'm currently working on a Rails app that allows users to import large CSVs of nested school data. A school has many teachers, a teacher has many classrooms, and a classroom has many students. The CSV therefore might look something like:

```
School 1
  Teacher 1
    Class 1
      Student 1
      Student 2
      Student 5
    Class 2
      Student 3
  Teacher 2
    Class 4
      Student 1
      Student 4
```

In a background job, I'm currently taking this CSV and, inside a database transaction block, building a gigantic school object in memory, which then attempts a single save. If the save fails, due to validation reasons or timeout, the transaction block will roll back my database to its previous state.

I've notice that the performance of this rollback is incredibly slow in production. I believe part of the reason is because there are concurrent read and writes to the database during the rollback. I am now contemplating whether or not it would be faster to manually cleanup the database via a :dependent => :delete_all approach. When I benchmark these in development, the manual cleanup is slightly slower than the rollback, but again, that is without the concurrent reads/writes.